# Android Emulator appears in strange UI

Tags: android-emulator, android-10

I am trying to create and run an AVD from command line using [Android's Command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line).

This means I used the `sdkmanager` to download the following modules:

- platform-tools
- emulator
- build-tools;29.0.2
- platforms;android-29
- system-images;android-29;default;x86_64

Afterwards I created an AVD using `call avdmanager create avd --name android29 --package "system-images;android-29;default;x86_64"` where I selected `no` for `Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile? [no]`.

When launching the AVD using `emulator @android29` and booting it up afterwards I get an old-fashioned bootscreen followed by an old-fashioned homescreen. The settings page however shows that Android 10 is in use.

What is the meaning or the reason of the old-fashioned looking UI?

[image: Screenshot Bootscreen]
[image: Screenshot Homescreen]
[image: Screenshot Android Version]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by using `system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86_64` instead of `"system-images;android-29;default;x86_64"`.